# group by a column and collapse all other columns without NA

Tags: r, group-by, na

I have a data frame and I am trying to collapse a bunch of columns by a group column called "id",
but I get a lot of NA values. Is there a way to remove NA, or use only unique values in the paste function?

```
df<- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                bar=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'NA'),
                foo=c('NA', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'NA', 'NA'))

library(plyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(unique(paste(., collapse = ","))))
```

I would like to remove the "NA"... 
Also, this functions takes longer than the basic aggregate, however I have not found the correct formula for the aggregate function either:

```
aggregate(df, by=list(df$id), paste, collapse=",")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the NAs strings or missing data?

Comment: What you are asking to do is un-frame a `data.frame`, since each column will now have different numbers of elements. Further, you have the literal string `"NA"` here, whereas R typically uses the object `NA` (or one of its specific `NA_*` descendants) to represent vague or not-available data. In this case, `unique` removes neither `"NA"` nor `NA`, nor does `paste`. Can you please post an example of what you expect the output to be? Also, please clarify on @HarroCyranka's question as to which type of NA you actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safer to first convert literal 'NA' values to true NA's:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., .=='NA', NA)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize_all(~paste(unique(na.omit(.)), collapse = ','))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id bar   foo  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a,b   b    
2     2 a     a    
3     3 b,c   b
```

Comment: I see... ok thank you avid_useR, this actually creates blanks with commas in between the NA values....

Comment: @user971102 I'm not sure what you mean by that. The output in my answer is exactly what I get when I run the code against your sample dataset. Do you perhaps have another dataset that my answer doesn't work? In that case, please provide that dataset in your question.

Comment: Both these answers work great and have helped clarify the problem a LOT, the part I had omitted (and hadn't realized) is that some columns were actually factors. If the row "mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)  %>%" is added, all works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ifelse():

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(unique(paste(ifelse(is.na(.), "", .), collapse = ","))))
```

Comment: I don't understand what the `unique` is doing (realizing you're just modifying OP's code...). Seems like it might do something worthwhile *inside* `paste()`, but outside `paste()` it is useless.

Comment: Also, a slightly simpler way to do the same thing might be `paste(na.omit(.), collapse = ",")`.

Comment: Also, if the columns are factors, this returns the factor encoding pasted together instead of the actual values.

Comment: @Gregor `na.omit` won't work with this because the 'NA''s are string literals in the sample data.

Comment: Thank you all for the very useful replies! I now understand the problem in my data is that I have a mix of formats in factors and characters and numeric values, and "NA" is a character not a missing value in R (understanding that from your comments), so all this creates sometimes blank values in between commas... I am not sure how to solve it yet but this is super useful and thank you!

Comment: I would say the correct way to deal with the `NA` issue is to fix it upstream. However this data gets created or imported in to R, there is a bug causing you to have character `"NA"` instead of missing value `NA`. Fix that bug at the source and you won't have an issue here.